# What is the logic of the recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Here is I have a factorial code using recursion.

```
class Factorial
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Factorial f = new Factorial();
       System.out.println(f.fact(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
    }

    private int fact(int num)
    {
        int result;
        if(num == 1)
             return 1;

        result = fact(num - 1) * num;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now to run this program, I did this

```
D:\>java Factorial 3
```

Now according to the logic when it enters the fact function, where num = 3, so it will skip to

```
result = fact(num - 1) * num;
```

Here it will become

```
result = fact(3 - 1) * num;
```

i.e. `result = fact(2) * num;`

In this step, I am little confused Does it execute whole step i.e.

```
result = fact(num - 1) * num;
```

or just the `fact(num - 1)`

According to the logic, what it should do is call the fact function. So, the control of the program again reaches to the start of the fact function where num = 2. It will again skip to

```
result = fact(num - 1) * num;
```

So, it will become

```
result = fact(2 - 1) * num;
```

i.e. `result = fact(1) * num;`

Now again, it should call the fact function without executing the whole syntax & again reaches to the start of the fact method where num = 1. This time num == 1 will be matched & 1 will be returned. Now it will return to

```
result = fact(num - 1) * num;
```

So, it will become

```
result = fact(1 - 1) * num;
```

i.e. `result = fact(0) * num;`

Now what will happen next ?

Am I going right ? If not what will be the correction ?

I dont clearly understand the flow of this recursion program.

Comment: Have you tried executing this in a debugger, and watching the call stack? It's not really clear what you're asking, to be honest.

Comment: `for num = 2 [..] So, it will become result = fact(1 - 1) * num;` why would you think that?

Comment: in every steps it executes `fact(num - 1)` and move forwards by calling the same method again but at the last step control moves backward in order to complete the method body

Comment: its not complex, just write down those steps as tree in a paper hen you will find out easily.

Comment: there's nowhere it only calculates `fact(num - 1)` but not multiply by num

Comment: Any decent debugger will do that. Download Eclipse for free and step through the code that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless we hit the stop condition:

```
fact(num) = fact(num - 1) * num;
```

Therefore:

```
fact(3) = fact(3 - 1) * 3;
```

Keeping in mind that fact(1) = 1 (from the if statement early in the `fact()` method):

```
fact(3) = fact(2) * 3;
fact(2) = fact(1) * 2;
fact(1) = 1;
```

Replacing each element:

```
fact(3) = 1 * 2 * 3;
```

The recursion is used to repeatedly dive deeper into the process until a stop condition is encountered - in this case when num = 1.

Answer (score 2):

> So, it will become
>
> ```
> result = fact(1 - 1) * num;
> ```

Nope. For `num = 2`,

```
result = fact(num - 1) * num;
```

becomes

```
result = 1 * num; // i.e. 1 * 2
```

`fact` **returns** a value, which means the **entire call** has to be replace with that value.
Not sure why you would even think `num` changes at all. You have no `num = ...` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I added some trace into the program. Execute it and see the output. Should be easy to follow.

```
package snippet;

class Factorial {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Factorial f = new Factorial();
        System.out.println(f.fact(Integer.parseInt("5")));
    }

    private int fact(int num) {
        int result;
        if (num == 1)
            return 1;

        result = fact(num - 1) * num;
        System.out.println("fact(" + num + ") = " + result + " = fact(" + (num - 1) + ") * " + num);
        return result;
    }
}
```

> fact(2) = 2 = fact(1) * 2
>   fact(3) = 6 = fact(2) * 3
>   fact(4) = 24 = fact(3) * 4
>   fact(5) = 120 = fact(4) * 5
>   120

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is right but you have made **3 basic errors**.
if we take your example;
First you run the program

```
D:\>java Factorial 3
```

then you have your **first mistake** because according to the logic all "num" have to be replaced by "3". So you get:

```
result = fact(3 - 1) * 3;
```

ie:

```
result = fact(2)*3;
```

then we have the **second mistake** because according to the definition of fact(num),

```
fact(2) = fact(2-1)*2
```

so we actually have

```
result = (fact(2-1)*2)*3
```

which is evaluated in

```
result = (fact(1)*2)*3
```

and here stand the **third mistake** because again according to fact(num) definition : `fact(1) = 1` and not `fact(1) = fact(1-1)*1` 
so we finally have:

```
result = ((1)*2)*3
```

To be more explicit if you follow all call sequence in the debugger you 'll have something like this( I put between brackets the value of the variable):

```
   private int fact(num{3})
    {
        int result;
        if(num{3}== 1)
             return 1;

        result = fact(num{3} - 1) * num{3};

            private int fact(num{3-1})
            {
                int result;
                if(num{3-1}== 1)

                result = fact(num{3-1} - 1) * num{3-1};

                    private int fact(num{3-1-1})
                    {
                        int result;
                        if(num{3-1-1}== 1)
                             return 1;
                    }

                return result{1*{3-1}};
            }
        return result{{1*{3-1}}*3};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The call f.fact(3) is expanding through the following steps:

```
1. result = fact(3 - 1) * 3 = fact(2) * 3
2. result = (fact(2 - 1) * 2) * 3 = (fact(1) * 2) * 3
3. result = 1 * 2 * 3 because fact(1) returns 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is correct, But it will never reach `fact(1-1) * 1` state ,as you return from method at   `if(num == 1)`.

`num` variable is limited to scope of method parameter. So for every call to `fact` method `num` variable is assigned a new value (i.e. num-1) and which is limited to that parameter scope only. So when `fact(num-1)` returns , value of num will be the original value and not the `num-1`.

Answer (score 1):

The flow of your example is like this
step 1. fact(3)*3;  //calling the function with num value 3
step 2. fact(2)*2;  //calling fact() method again with num=2
step 3. fact(1)*1;  //now num == 1 will be matched & 1 will be returned.
    i. e.,
1 * 1 = **1**;      //now, steps 2 and 1 will be performed respectively
step 2. 1 * 2 = **2**;
step 1. 2 * 3 = **6**;

So, the final answer will be **6**
**Note:** In step 3, the value is **returned**, so it will not again call this
 result = fact(0) * num; //which you have mentioned in question.